# What should i replace here to make my exercise work?

Tags: c++

I would like to multiply the even digits from a number, for example if I enter 22, I want the program to multiply 2*2. What should I replace in my program to complete my goal?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int result;
    cout << "Enter Number bigger then 9" << endl;
    cin>>n;
    if(n<9)
{
    cout<< "You entered a number smaller then 9" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "You Entered: " <<n<<endl;
    while (n >= 100)
    {
        n /= 10;
        return n % 10;

    }

    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        result = n*n;
        cout << "The Result from multiple digits is : "<<result<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
           cout << "The Digit is not even"<< endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest the `return` statement.  It will end your program.

Comment: You may want to move your `if` statement to inside the `while` loop.

Comment: What is the current behaviour of the code? Have you got an example of input and its behaviour, and your expected behaviour? What is the output if you use 61, or 66, 99?

Comment: I highly recommend using a debugger and single stepping through your code.  You will find a lot of issues this way.

Comment: As Thomas Matthews said, learn to debug, teach you far better lesson than posting here ever would

Answer (score 0):

logic is wrong.
you need to extract each digit, find if it is divisible by 2 and multiply.
here is one way to do so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int result = 1;
    cout << "Enter Number bigger then 9" << endl;
    cin>>n;
    if(n<9)
    {
        cout<< "You entered a number smaller then 9" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You Entered: " <<n<<endl;
        int i = 10;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            int remainder = n % i;
            cout << "remainder: " << remainder <<endl;
            if ((remainder % 2) == 0)
            {
                result *= remainder;
            }
            n = n/10;
        }

        cout << "result: " << result << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```